# Filtering navigation properties in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ query that fetches a lot of data (shown below). This query is causing a timeout issue so I'm trying to filter it so that it only gets the needed records. I'm trying to get the Orders for a specific date. The date field is in the Order table but how do I muster that into the LINQ query below. I tried adding .Where(...) after the second .Include but that gives me errors.

```
var productEntities = _context.Set<Product>()
            .Include(p => p.OrderItems)
            .Include(p => p.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.Order))
            .Include(p => p.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.Order.Client))                
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet with the `.Where(..)` call? Can you specify the error? I'm afraid we need a little more information to work with.

Comment: If you try to get *Orders for a specific date*, why don't you query the `_context.Orders` then?

Answer (score 0):

I believe  [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) is right, if you go with orders first you actually narrowing down your Sql joins in the database as well. I would say try filtering Orders first with date and then use SelectMany to retrieve the Products, I don't know what's your tables relations exactly but the idea is something like:

```
var productEntities = _context.Set<Order>()
        .Where(o=>o.Date>=_dateFrom &&o.Date<=_dateTo)
        .SelectMany(o=>o.OrderItem.Product)     
        .Include(p => p.OrderItems)
        .Include(p => p.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.Order))
        .Include(p => p.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.Order.Client))                
        .ToList();
```